# Does web worker reload the imported module every time?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

When I am reading a opensource project using web worker, I found that once a module is imported by the worker, then call to the imported module will cause reload of the whole module.

For example, main thread:

a.js

```
const  T = new Date().getTime(); //init the variable once the moudle is loaded
export default T;
```

worker.js:

```
import T from a;

const a  = T; // this will result in different value for the varible `T`
```

Is this the desired implemention? How to avoid this or if I can to get the global-initiated varible inside a worker ?

Comment: I can confirm with latest Chrome Version 99.0.4844.82 (Official Build) (64-bit) this still occurs.   If you import a module into both a web worker and a non-worker module that results in the imported module being executed twice.  Further, the imported module appears to be re-executed each time you reference an imported object in the worker!   Worth noting that Firefox still doesn't support module workers at this time.

Comment: ...each time you reference an imported object **from an event handler** registered in the worker...