# SvelteKit or Vite re-runs imports that should only run once

Tags: svelte, vite, es6-modules, web-worker, sveltekit

**UPDATE:**
A fresh SvelteKit install and barebones setup DOES NOT cause the same behavior. My assumption is that the issue may come from the `ComLink` dependency or web workers in general. I'm leaving the question up and adding a `webworker` tag in case anyone has run into this before; if I find a solution, I'll either report back or delete the question, depending on how much the problem was related to me being a dummy.

**Problem:**
I've got two versions of the same app running mostly the same code, one set up with Svelte and Vite and the other with SvelteKit and Vite (both using TypeScript 5.0). The SvelteKit app appears to be re-running imported code on every import, which is not desirable.

Transferring my Vite settings in the Svelte app to the SvelteKit app doesn't change the SvelteKit app's behavior. My intention is to switch from Svelte to SvelteKit, but this is causing problems. My thanks for any guidance, direction, or search terms anyone can provide.

**Example:**
I set up app state in `State.ts`, which is imported in several script files. I added a `console.log("STATE setup")` at the top of `State.ts`. In the Svelte app, "State setup" is logged exactly once, despite being imported in multiple files. In the SvelteKit app, "State setup" is logged ~8 times (once for every import), and then again every couple of seconds on a loop (which I think is caused because code is re-run when imported).

So, `State.ts` is:

```
console.log("State imported");
export const state = "My State";
```

Given that three additional files (`auth.ts`, `config.ts`, and the root `+layout.svelte`) import `State.ts` in this fashion:

```
import { state } from `$lib/app/State.ts`
```

the Svelte app logs the following:

```
State imported
```

and the SvelteKit app logs the following:

```
State imported
State imported
State imported
```

with `auth.ts`, `config.ts`, and the root `+layout.svelte` file.

**Vite Settings:**
in `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig, searchForWorkspaceRoot } from 'vite';
import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        nodePolyfills(),
        sveltekit()
    ],
    resolve: { alias: { './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser' } },
    server: {
        fs: {
            allow: [
                searchForWorkspaceRoot(process.cwd()),
                "/build-scripts"
            ]
        }
    },
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        target: "es2020"
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            target: "es2020"
        }
    }
});
```

**Additional (possibly unrelated) info:**

- "vite": "^4.3.0"
- "typescript": "^5.0.0"
- "svelte": "^3.54.0"
- "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^2.0.2"
- "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0"
- I'm using `@sveltejs/adapter-static` -- I know this defeats some of the purpose of switching to SvelteKit, but I like having routing taken care of and I like the project structure
- This wasn't a huge problem until I tried to implement a long-running web worker, which was instantiated multiple times on a loop until the app crashed
- The `nodePolyfills()` in `plugins` is intended to address AWS Cognito `global is not defined` and `global` and `window` not defined errors in the web worker context

Comment: When you talk about this being an issue on imported code, it might be helpful to show an example of how you're importing code (is it just `import { foo } from 'bar';`?) and a bare bones file that shows this logging behavior when imported.

Comment: @Mordred Thank you. I've updated the Example section with a bare-bones setup--I hope this helps provide some context.

Comment: A fresh install and bare-bones setup as provided in my example DOES NOT cause the same behavior. I've updated the question to say that. My current suspicions lie with web workers: either using Surma's ComLink tool, Svelte stores in a web worker, ts-proto in a web worker, or some combination thereof.

Comment: I did a little investigating and it seems it's the WebWorkers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423420/does-web-worker-reload-the-imported-module-every-time) where they say imports are reloaded in each webworkers even if already loaded in the parent.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this! Looks like it may be related to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423420/does-web-worker-reload-the-imported-module-every-time#comment126559377_52423420) specifically. Doing some tests to confirm and determine if there are viable workarounds.

Comment: I will likely provide an answer with what will be my solution, but what you discovered relates directly to my question and explains what was causing the reloads. If you would like to formulate your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept and comment with my exact solution.

Comment: Nah go for it. If you've got a work around that'll be more helpful as an answer rather than a comment.